# How to use a functor instead of lambda function

Tags: c++, priority-queue, functor

I was trying to solve a problem from Leetcode.

Problem description:

Given a n x n matrix where each of the rows and columns are sorted in ascending order, find the kth smallest element in the matrix.

Note that it is the kth smallest element in the sorted order, not the kth distinct element.

I solved it like this:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    int kthSmallest(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& matrix, int k) {

        auto comp_gt = [&matrix](std::pair<int ,int> a, std::pair<int ,int> b)
        {
            return matrix[a.first][a.second] > matrix[b.first][b.second];
        };

        m = matrix.size();
        if (m == 0) return 0;
        n = matrix[0].size();
        if (n == 0) return 0;        

        std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, int>, 
                            std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>, 
                            decltype(comp_gt)> min_heap(comp_gt);

        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            min_heap.emplace(0, j);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < k-1; ++i)
        {
            int r = min_heap.top().first;
            int c = min_heap.top().second;
            min_heap.pop();

            if (r != m - 1)
            {
                min_heap.emplace(r+1, c);
            }
        }

        return matrix[min_heap.top().first][min_heap.top().second];
    }

private:
    int m;
    int n;
};
```

This code works. However, when I tried to replace the lambda function with a functor, I wrote the functor like this:

```cpp
class comp_gt
{
    bool operator () (std::pair<int, int> a, std::pair<int, int> b, std::vector<std::vector<int>>& matrix)
    {
        return matrix[a.first][a.second] > matrix[b.first][b.second];
    }
};
```

then I realized I didn't know how to pass the `matrix` to a functor like `[&matrix]` in a lambda function.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the reference in the constructor of the functor. Note that the below code is equivalent to your lambda, but with the `mutable` modifier.

```
class comp_gt
{

    public:
        using Matrix = std::vector<std::vector<int>>;

        comp_gt(Matrix& matrix) : matrix{matrix}{}
        bool operator () (std::pair<int, int> a, std::pair<int, int> b, std::vector<std::vector<int>>& matrix)
        {
             return matrix[a.first][a.second] > matrix[b.first][b.second];
        }

    private:

        Matrix& matrix;

};
```

Then use it as:

```
comp_gt comp{matrix};
```

Comment: As far as I know, overloaded operator should take only two parameters for priority_queues. Why priority_queue does not create compilation/linking error with a function object as a custom comparator that has a overloaded function operator with an third additional parameter 'matrix' ?

Answer (score 1):

"How to use a functor instead of lambda function" - Create a class with `operator()` (that optionally captures variables). A lambda is *nothing but* syntactic sugar (an easier way) to write such a (functor) class.

Answer (score 0):

This is done by passing it to the comparator's ***constructor***:

```
class comp_gt
{
  std::vector<std::vector<int>>& matrix;

  comp_gt(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& matrix) : matrix{matrix} {}
```

Now, your existing `operator()` can use it normally.

Then, when you actually go about constructing the comparator, you just construct it normally and pass the appropriate parameter to the constructor. Let's say you wanted to use your comparator with `std::sort`:

```
comp_gt comparator{some_matrix};

std::sort(something.begin(), something.end(), comparator);
```

Using this comparator with `std::priority_queue` is analogous.